# After Update Android SDK - Layout Not Display

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am updating Android SDK currently then after not display xml file in design view and says

> "**LayoutLib is too recent. Update your tool!**"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your Eclipse plugin up to date? In Eclipse go Help -> Check for Updates.